# How to achieve windowing and shuffling in tensorflow model of two inputs and two outputs?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, time-series, windowing

I'm analysing daily power consumption of a washing machine. My dataset consists of 4 columns namely:

- Unix timestamp
- aggregate power consumption by all devices in the house
- Power consumption by washing machine
- Binary data ( 0 when washing machine was off and 1 when it was on).

`Unix` and `aggregate` are supposed to be inputs while `power` and `binary` are supposed to be outputs. I'm feeding all these features as separate numpy arrays.

Here is my model:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import Input, Model


input1 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(None, ))
input2 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(None,))
inputs= tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=1)([input1, input2])
inputs = tf.keras.layers.Reshape((-1,2))(inputs)
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=16, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding="causal", activation="relu",input_shape=[None,2,1])(inputs)
x = tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.GRU(128, activation="tanh", return_sequences=True))(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.GRU(256, activation="tanh", return_sequences=True))(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation="tanh")(x)
o1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="linear",name="ed")(x)
o2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid",name="sd")(x)

model = Model(inputs=[input1,input2], outputs=[o1, o2])

model.compile(loss={'ed': 'mean_squared_error', 
                    'sd': 'binary_crossentropy'},
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics={'ed': tf.keras.metrics.MeanSquaredError(name="mean_squared_error", dtype=None),
                       'sd': tf.keras.metrics.BinaryCrossentropy(name="binary_crossentropy", dtype=None, from_logits=False, label_smoothing=0)})
```

Since this is pure time series analysis , windowing and shuffling are necessary. But , I don't know how to do this with multiple inputs and outputs.

Usually this the code most people use for shuffling and windowing:

```
def windowed_dataset(series, window_size, batch_size, shuffle_buffer):
    series = tf.expand_dims(series, axis=-1)
    ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(series)
    ds = ds.window(window_size + 1, shift=1, drop_remainder=True)
    ds = ds.flat_map(lambda w: w.batch(window_size + 1))
    ds = ds.shuffle(shuffle_buffer)
    ds = ds.map(lambda w: (w[:-1], w[1:]))
    return ds.batch(batch_size).prefetch(1)
```

I don't see how this can be used for multiple inputs and outputs.

Comment: As a side note, you shouldn't supply `timestamp` as an input to the model. Instead, you should have a sequence of `power` arranged according to their `timestamp`. Hence, you would have only one input which is a sequence of aggregate power usages.

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal if I did that I wouldn't be able to get the predicted power consumption for a specific time period (say 9-11 am).